# Ruby on Rails: Order users based on average ratings with most reviews?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rating

I'm able to display the items and their reviews that are within the shop. How do I get the top items with most reviews? My reviews are in another database table than shop and item.

**Controller**

```
@shop = Shop.find(params[:id]) 
@item = Item.where(:shop_name => @shop.name)
```

**View**

```
<% @item.each do |u| %>
  <%= u.reviews.average('rating') %>
  <%= u.reviews.count %>
<% end %>
```

Is there an easy method where I can order based on the highest rating with most reviews or something? Or maybe its better to separate highest rating and most reviews and let users click on a link to filter?

Thanks

EDIT:

So I have a `shop`, `item`, `review` table.

In my **items model**

```
has_many :reviews, as: :reviewable
has_many :shops
```

In my **reviews model** and **shops model** is

```
belongs_to :user
```

In my reviews table, its set so when a user reviews an item, it adds a record to the database, and I use the `average` of all the records thats associated with that item and display it that within the shop.

Comment: Could You share more details about You tables and models, probably a fine SQL query could help.

Comment: @EdgarsJekabsons I added some details, does it make a little more sense?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood correctly Your ER model, You can try this:

```
@items = Item.where(:shop_name => @shop.name).joins(:reviews)
  .select("items.id, avg(reviews.rating) as average_rating, count(reviews.id) as number_of_reviews")
  .group("items.id")
  .order("average_rating DESC, number_of_reviews DESC")
```

There could some typos, but You get the idea. Also probably You will want to create some kind of weighted score, otherwise in this case item with one 5 star review will be higher than item with fifty 4 star reviews.

Also all the custom columns I defined in `select` block will be of string type, so You will need to typecast those manually if You will do any arithmetic operations on them.

Comment: I'm testing out this code and I'm getting error function on the `average(reviews.rating)`

Comment: awesome this works! I'm assuming this method would be very slow in the long run?

Comment: Actually it shouldn't (to some extent of course) if You index Your tables/columns correctly. But that's a completely different topic and I need to see more SQL and details on table structure to suggest anything.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Maybe when I get there, I'll try to ask a new question.

Comment: What if I need to do a count on `@items`? Currently this throws an error in my similar case