# How to display highest rated albums through a has_many reviews relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, has-many

I'm setting up a simple ruby/rails app where users can review albums. On an album's show page I average all the user reviews associated with that album through this code in my albums controller

```
def show
  @album = Album.find_by_id(params[:id])
  if @album.reviews.present?
    @ratings = Review.where(album_id: @album).average(:rating).truncate(2)
  else
    render 'show'
  end
end
```

This gives me an average rating for each album. On my home page (routed through a different controller) I want to display the top 7 albums with the highest average rating.

What I originally did was put this code into the separate home page controller:

```
@albums = Album.all
@ratings = @albums.each {|album| album.reviews.average(:rating).to_f}
@ranked_ratings =  @ratings.sort_by {|rating| rating}
@top_seven = @ranked_ratings.reverse[0...7]
```

I thought I found the solution until I realized all I'm showing is the last 7 albums entered into the database.

Going back to the drawing board I have been able to get an array of all the albums (each element within the array is a list of reviews associated with that album) with this code in my controller:

```
@albums = Album.all
@ratings = @albums.collect {|album| album.reviews}
```

I'm stuck at this point trying to figure out how to cycle through @ratings and find the average rating for each album_id, then order those records by the highest average rating and display them in a view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `@albums = Album.joins(:reviews).select("album.id, avg(reviews.rating) as average_rating).group("album.id").order("average_rating DESC")`

I extrapolated it from:  [Ruby on Rails: Order users based on average ratings with most reviews?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339140/ruby-on-rails-order-users-based-on-average-ratings-with-most-reviews)

**Update:**

try this instead: `@albums = Album.joins(:reviews).select("*, avg(reviews.rating) as average_rating").group("albums.id").order("average_rating DESC")`

Comment: Yeah, this is the kind of stuff databases are made for.  Probably best to let the SQL handle it and not sort & collect in Ruby.

Comment: I'm getting a lot of syntax errors with your suggested solution, trying to refactor right now, should avg be capitalized?

Comment: Try changing avg to average than.

Comment: I changed it to this `@albums = Album.joins(:reviews).select("album.id", average(reviews.rating), as: average_rating).group("album.id").order("average_rating DESC")` but I'm getting a undefined local variable or method `reviews' error

Comment: Or like you said capitalize to AVG.

Comment: The quotations in the select should be `.select("...")` so that they are at the beginning and end of the select statement.