# .joins method returning incorrect id's

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, nomethoderror

***UPDATE***

I have a simple rails app with a home page displaying the highest rated albums, using this code in my controller (used code from this solution: [How to display highest rated albums through a has_many reviews relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20852887/how-to-display-highest-rated-albums-through-a-has-many-reviews-relationship)):

```
def home
    @top_ratings = Album.joins(:reviews).select("*, avg(reviews.rating) as average_rating").group("albums.id").order("average_rating DESC")

    @top_seven = @top_ratings[0...7]
end
```

In my home.html.erb file I am displaying each album and have a link_to tag that takes the user to the album's show page:

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <% @top_seven.each do |album| %>
      <td><%= link_to (image_tag album.picture, size: '150x150'), album_url(album)  %>    </td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

The data appears fine, however when I click on the link, I get a "undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass" error on the album's show page.

On my rails server I noticed that the album id's associated with the @top_ratings and @top_seven variables are different than the album's actual id, which is why I am getting the error.

Does anyone know how to refactor @top_ratings so that it will return the highest rated albums with their *correct* id number so that the link will work properly?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Have you seen the request? Is `:id` actually getting sent in the `params` hash?

Comment: Yes in my rails server I am getting `Parameters: {"id"=>"28"}` when I click on the album link

Comment: Does this happen with every album, or just specific ones?

Comment: See my recent revision to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By changing the code above from this:

```
<td><%= link_to (image_tag album.picture, size: '150x150'), album_url(album) %></td>
```

To this:

```
<td><%= link_to (image_tag album.picture, size: '150x150'), album_url(album.album_id) %></td>
```

It will pull the correct id for the album and allow the link_to to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

When `Album.find_by_id(params[:id])` has no match, `@album` becomes `nil`. `NilClass` does not have a method named `name`.

Comment: I edited my question above, but essentially the @top_ratings variable is returning the correct list of albums, but they have the wrong id numbers, which is why the link_to isn't working, I'm currently looking into finding a way to refactor the variable so it returns the albums with their correct id number.