# ERROR: column "engagements.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

i have the following query which works

```
@engagements = Engagement.includes(:participation).where(influencer_authorization_id: current_influencer.id).group_by { |p| p.status }
```

i am trying to use the Database function instead of the Ruby/Rails function to group and the following is my code

```
engagements = Engagement.where(influencer_authorization_id: current_influencer.id).group("status")
```

But i am getting the following error

> ERROR:  column "engagements.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
>   LINE 1: SELECT "engagements".* FROM "engagements" WHERE "engagements...
>                  ^

**Update**

I tried doing the following but still doesnt work

```
engagements = Engagement.select("engagements.*").where(influencer_authorization_id: current_influencer.id).group("engagement.status")
```

**ERROR**

> ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "engagement"
>   LINE 1: ...ents"."influencer_authorization_id" = $1 GROUP BY engagement...
>                                                                ^

Comment: `Enumerable#group_by` is very different from SQL's `GROUP BY`. `group_by` is for, more or less, building arrays whose elements are the same with respect to a block. `GROUP BY` is for grouping rows so that an aggregate function (such as `count`, `max`, ...) can be applied to each group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use postgres?
The problem is that database can't decide what to show for e.g. 'id' column when 'status' is the same for several records. You can manually write select statement and use aggregate functions. 
I think this [PostgreSQL -must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18061285/postgresql-must-appear-in-the-group-by-clause-or-be-used-in-an-aggregate-functi) and this [GroupingError: ERROR: column must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20942477/groupingerror-error-column-must-appear-in-the-group-by-clause-or-be-used-in-an?rq=1) are related

Comment: i tried that but am still getting an error. have updated the question

Comment: @HarshaMV that should be group("engagements.status") instead of group("engagement.status").
Also if that won't work please share .to_sql output of query