# Fine on SQLite, broken in Postgresql: column must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: postgresql, sqlite

I have a query which works fine on SQLite, but when I run it on the same data in Postgresql I get:

> column "role.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

I have three tables, for people, exhibitions, and a table that links the two: "One person in one exhibition performing a particular role" (such as "Artist" or "Curator"):

```
CREATE TABLE "person" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                       "name" varchar(255));

CREATE TABLE "exhibition" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                           "name" varchar(255));

CREATE TABLE "role" (`id` integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                     `name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
                     `exhibition_id` integer NOT NULL,
                     `person_id` integer NOT NULL, 
                     FOREIGN KEY(`exhibition_id`) REFERENCES `exhibition`(`id`),
                     FOREIGN KEY(`person_id`) REFERENCES `person`(`id`));
```

I want to display the people involved in an exhibition ordered by how many things they've done. So, I get the IDs of the people in an exhibition (`1,2,3,4`) and then do this:

```
SELECT
    *,
    COUNT(person.id) AS role_count
FROM person
INNER JOIN role
ON person.id = role.person_id
WHERE person.id IN ( 1, 2, 3, 4 )
GROUP BY person.id
ORDER BY role_count DESC
```

That orders the people by `role_count`, which is the number of roles they've had across all exhibitions

It works fine on SQLite, but not in Postgresql. I've tried putting `role.id` into the `GROUP BY` (instead of, and as well as, `person.id`) but that changes the results.

Comment: It's actually the other way round: SQLite is broken. This kind of `group by` is invalid and wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know when you struggle for ages, post an SO question, and then immediately stumble on the answer?

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20942527/250962) I realised that I couldn't select `role.id` (which the `SELECT *` is implicitly doing) as it wasn't in the `GROUP BY`.

I couldn't add it to the `GROUP BY` (because that changes the results) so the solution was to not select it.

So I changed the `SELECT` part to:

```
SELECT
    person.*,
    COUNT(person.id) AS role_count
FROM person
...
```

Now `role.id` is not being selected. And that works.

If I needed any other fields from the `role` table, like `name`, I could add those explicitly too:

```
SELECT
    person.*,
    role.name,
    COUNT(person.id) AS role_count
FROM person
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Just like the error says, Standard SQL doesn't let you `SELECT` anything other than one of the `GROUP BY` columns or a call to an [aggregate function](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html).  (For a logical reason: How would the RDBMS know *which* `role.id` to select when there are multiple rows to select from within a group?)  PostgreSQL actually enforces this rule; SQLite ignores it and just returns data from an arbitrary row in the group.

As you discovered, omitting `role.id` from the `SELECT` fixes your error.  But if you *do* want SQLite's behavior of selecting the ID from an arbitrary row, you can simply wrap it in an aggregate function, e.g., `SELECT MAX(role.id)` instead of just `SELECT role.id`).